# Changing animation speed at runtime

Tags: unity, animation, mecanim

Is there a way in Unity to change the animation speed of an animation managed by an animator controller (Mecanim)?

I'd like to do that at runtime so that I can speedup and slow down an animation based on conditions in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the Speed of the Animator itself, which may be adequate for what you are trying to do:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html

However, if you need to adjust each animation individually, you will need to use the AnimationState object instead.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-speed.html