# Change animation speed through the editor in Unity

Tags: unity, animation, animation-states

How can I change the speed of the animation through the editor if I have the following animation structure?

[image]

I would like Adult1@walk to play faster.

Comment: Again, I would recommend that you [consult the documentation first](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlendTree-AdditionalOptions.html) when you have a question about the use of a tool. Much of this material is already covered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing animation speed at runtime](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102132/changing-animation-speed-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your Blend Tree.

In the section where you assign animations to the blend tree, there is a column for changing the animation speed. Change the value there from 1 (normal speed) to make the animation on that line play faster or slower.

[image: Screenshot of the Blend Tree inspector showing field labelled "Changes animation speed."]